# Keyboard Volume Buttons Don't Change Connected Bluetooth volume

Tags: sound, xubuntu, keyboard, bluetooth

tried messing around with a lot of different things and following different threads but to no avail, so i'm hoping someone here can help me.

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on an inspiron 7537, bought last year. After months of running around the interwebs like a headless chicken, i've finally, finally managed to get working bluetooth speakers.  However one problem remains - the Volume up and down buttons on the keyboard have no effect of the bluetooth speakers when connected. This is turning out to be a real pain. Ive tried settings-settings editor and looking for xfce-mixer as advised in some posts but this doesn't exist in my version of xubuntu.

Can anyone point me in the right direction??

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) If you go to system settings - sound, can you change the volume there???

Comment: yes i can change it there alright

Comment: So the keyboard buttons aren't bound to the master volume?  (does clicking the speaker icon and changing the volume there work with the BlueTooth speakers?)

Comment: No the keyboard buttons work with the laptop speakers but not when the bluetooth speakers are plugged in.  Clicking the speaker icon and changing the volume works with the bluetooth speakers.

Comment: scratch that - moving the slider on the speaker icon doesn't change the volume on bluetooth speakers.  in Volume Control, the keyboard volume buttons move the slider on Built In Analogue Stereo

Comment: OK i've finally figured it out, so simple yet i overlooked it completely.  in Volume Control - Output Devices tab i clicked on the green icon 'Set As Fallback' next to the bluetooth device and that did it. It had remained on the Built-In Audio Analog Stereo device.  Thanks a million for you help anyway!

Comment: Ah...  Only saw now that you've solved your own question.  Could you please convert your last comment to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 8):

OK I've finally figured it out, so simple yet I overlooked it completely.

In **Volume Control > Output Devices** tab I clicked on the green icon *Set As Fallback* next to the Bluetooth device and that did it. It had remained on the *Built-In Audio Analog Stereo* device.

Thanks a million for your help anyway!

Comment: i wonder why isn't this the default thing that happens when you connect a bluetooth speaker. now we have a bunch of people saying "that other OS is better because we don't have to google stuff like this"...

Comment: I had same problem, but fiachrafiachra's answer works for me.
The "Set As Fallback" is on PulsaAudio volume control. It can be run by command "pavucontrol" on terminal prompt.
If it is not exist, need to install.

Answer (score 3):

Found this at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1404729:

Just edit this file:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

And add the following:

```
# automatically switch to newly-connected devices
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

After adding above lines to file run the following in terminal:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

You will need to disconnect and reconnect your Bluetooth device.

Worked just fine for me, maybe it works for you too!